# Вставить содержимое HTML-файла в div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть HTML-страница, на которую необходимо выводить различный текст, а потом взаимодействовать с ним (onСlick и тд), поэтому `<iframe>` не подходит.

Особенность текста в том, что он хранится в формате HTML, так как некоторые слова являются ссылками.

Подскажите, как я могу вставить содержимое HTML-файла в другой файл HTML так, чтобы работали ссылки?

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('div.container').load('drugoj.html');
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]